# Hide confidential data when sending code on github

Tags: mysql, r, github

In the script hosted on github I am querying data from MySQL database:

```
db_connect <- function() {
  db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = "odvjet12_gfi",
                  host = "xxxxx",
                  port = 3306L,
                  user = "xxxx",
                  password = "xxxx")
  return(db)
}
```

I would like to know, how can I use this function but hide my confidential data, so that nobody can see them on Github?

Comment: There are a few options for this.  See https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/11/how-to-store-and-use-authentication-details-with-r.html

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem